# Margins are not being enforced latex

Tags: pdftex, margins, sharelatex

I'm trying to set the margins to be 15mm on each side, but when I measure with a ruler after it is printed on an a4 sheet, the value seems to be off by 3mm (i.e., 18mm) on each side.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage[left=15mm, top=15mm,right=15mm, bottom=15mm, footskip=3mm, headsep=2mm]{geometry}
```

What am I doing wrong?
For some background: This is being done on ShareLatex

Comment: Just to gather more data about your case: How does the margin of the printout compare to the PDF?

Comment: Did you use any options while printing, something like `fit to paper` or similar?

Comment: @StefanSchroeder, I am not entirely sure how to check the margins on a evince/adobereader.

Comment: @samcarter, I tried to print with and without it. Both don't seem to help

Comment: Some printers can't print right up to the edges of the paper. (Tell us what model of printer you are using!) Something might have automatically scaled the image of the page to fit into the printable area, even if you didn't ask for that. Do you have an option "print at 100%" somewhere in your print dialogs - if so, try it.

Comment: While some applications are available to measure distances on the screen, they all depend on a correct setting of your graphics driver (dpi-setting). A foolproof (no offense!) method is to re-scale the page on your monitor and measure directly on you screen (if it works, it's not stupid!).

Comment: @alephzero, this is the printer that i'm using: `MP C5504(A)SP`. Yes, it does offer print to 100% and I can try doing.

Comment: @StefanSchroeder you know the width of the PDF page (210mm for A4) so you can compensate for any scaling errors on your monitor. Another check would be to temporarily change the margins to `0mm` so you don't actually need to measure anything.